# How to resolve Mercurial conflicts through bitbucket web interface?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

(Asked a couple weeks ago on the Atlassian forums. Not a peep there...)

I have a fork of the pylint mercurial repo: https://bitbucket.org/smontanaro/pylint

Bitbucket tells me I'm about a bazillion commits behind, and when I ask the web interface to sync with this: https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint it tells me the sync can't complete because of conflicts. How do I resolve those conflicts through the web interface? Or is that not possible and I have to do something else?

Answer (score 2):

Conflict resolution has to happen on a local machine.  There's no way to merge on the bitbucket (or github) interfaces.  Check out `hg merge`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're telling me. I tried to sync through the web interface. Are you telling me I can't really do that (even though it's a function the site provides), that conflicts aren't supposed to happen when you sync through the web interface, or that when conflicts happen during the sync operation I have to resort to the command line to resolve conflicts?

Comment: When not-automatically-resolvable conflicts arise you have to resolve them through a merge tool on your local system, which you can launch from the command line. Merging _is_ coding, and there's only so much a system can do for you automatically.  None of the web interfaces that I know of provide an interactive merge tool.  They handle the automatics and let you know to fire up your editor if that wasn't enough.